# Two screensavers running at the same time

Tags: ubuntu-mate, screensaver

I have xscreensaver installed.

When I move my mouse, it stops the screensaver that is viewable.

But when I hit a key, there is another screensaver running.

I only want xscreensaver running.

I do not know how to diagnose this.

Comment: "When I move my mouse, it stops, but there is another screensaver running at the same time?" needs clarification. It reads like both a statement and a question.

Comment: @DK Bose I made some edits.